# Anchor animating widget in center using stack widget

Tags: flutter, animation, positioning

Im trying to position multiple widgets on a screen.

One of the widgets is supposed to animate, while the rest are not. I'm currently trying to do this using the stack widget, but the animation runs with the animated widget anchored to wherever i define the positional parameters to. If i define top: 100, left: 100 the animating widget animates with anchor at this point, and not at its center as it would with a regular column and row setup.

How can I make the animating widget anchor at center?

**What i have tried:**
1. using a stack widget with normal top left parameters
2. using a stack widget with positioned.fill and align, Alignment.center.

**Code:**

```
import 'package:corona_app/commons/moreInfo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreenMain extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeScreenMainState createState() => _HomeScreenMainState();
}

class _HomeScreenMainState extends State<HomeScreenMain>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation sizeAnimation;
  AnimationController sizeAnimationController;
  bool reversed = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sizeAnimationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    sizeAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 200, end: 170).animate(sizeAnimationController);
    sizeAnimationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    sizeAnimationController.forward();
    sizeAnimation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed && reversed == false) {
        sizeAnimationController.repeat(reverse: true);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    sizeAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: defaultValues.backGroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: defaultValues.appBarBackgroundColor,
      ),
      body: Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible, children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: 100,
          left: 100,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Suche Läuft',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )),
                    width: this.sizeAnimation.value,
                    height: this.sizeAnimation.value,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 10, color: Colors.grey[600])
                        ],
                        gradient: RadialGradient(colors: [
                          Colors.grey[700],
                          Colors.grey[800],
                        ]))),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 60, 0, 0),
              child: MoreInfo(),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work as intended.

Added the bottom and right properties, and set the alignment property to Alignment.center.

This did the trick.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you did please? I have a similar problem